# Why is my variable undefine in the for loop statement?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Why is the variable $myVar undefined in the for loop statement while defined in the if statement as shown below (blade template in Laravel 5.2)?

```
  $myVar = [];

  @if (empty($myVar))
     Var is empty.
  @endif

  @foreach ($myVar as $var)
    <li>{{$var}}</li>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Perhaps because it needs to be define in php tags in your template, otherwise it should simply be literal displayed text

Comment: @Mark it's defined in a controller?

Comment: Are you getting an error on the second one?

Comment: And how are you injecting it from the controller into the view?

Comment: wrong Parameter passing I found out, thanks Mark for your help reminding me about the controller, and to kojow7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try also isset

```
$myVar = [];

@if (empty($myVar))
   Var is empty.
@endif

@if (isset($myVar))
   Var is isset.
@endif


@foreach ($myVar as $var)
   <li>{{$var}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `empty` includes `isset` as part of its logic.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That is correct, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: @scaisEdge The answer is not right, nor is it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I made it worked by changing return view('process', withMyVar($myVar);  with view('process', compact($myVar);